# Docker images cannot be installed when Cloudflare Warp service is active

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cloudflare, cloudflare-warp

Recently I've installed EndeavourOS Artemis which comes with firewalld installed and running. Moreover I've installed "cloudflare warp" and is running as a background service.

When trying to install any Docker images I'm getting error messages, for example, for **Postgraphile** I get:

```
=> ERROR [2/4] RUN npm install -g postgraphile                                                                                  86.2s
------                                                                                                                                 
 > [2/4] RUN npm install -g postgraphile:                                                                                              
#0 86.09 npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN                                                                                                       
#0 86.09 npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo                                                                                                  
#0 86.09 npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN                                                                                                      
#0 86.10 npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/postgraphile failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org
#0 86.10 
#0 86.10 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#0 86.10 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-08-26T15_41_19_407Z-debug-0.log
```

For **Dart** I get:

```
=> ERROR [build 4/6] RUN dart pub get                                                                                          124.0s
------                                                                                                                                 
 > [build 4/6] RUN dart pub get:                                                                                                       
#0 0.616 Resolving dependencies...                                                                                                     
#0 33.81 It looks like pub.dartlang.org is having some trouble.                                                                        
#0 33.81 Pub will wait for a while before trying to connect again.
#0 123.8 Got socket error trying to find package build_runner at https://pub.dartlang.org.
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dart pub get]: exit code: 69
```

After googling I discovered this problem is related to DNS and docker (reference [here](https://github.com/StefanScherer/dockerfiles-windows/issues/270)), so after making any try-and-error tests, the problem is solved if I stopped Cloudflare service:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop warp-svc
```

For future Docker images being installed I'd have to previously stop `warp-svc` service. So is there any canonical solution (for example, adding rules to *firewalld* or *docker-compose* or *cloudflare warp*)?

I don't know if this is related to the current problem:

```
$ sudo systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-08-26 10:06:01 -05; 1h 58min ago
       Docs: man:firewalld(1)
   Main PID: 8894 (firewalld)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 19087)
     Memory: 28.4M
        CPU: 709ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
             └─8894 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/firewalld --nofork --nopid

ago 26 10:06:01 antares systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
ago 26 10:06:01 antares systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
ago 26 10:06:02 antares firewalld[8894]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/bin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i br-04cf50298f29 -o br-04cf5029>
ago 26 10:06:02 antares firewalld[8894]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/bin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP' fa>
ago 26 10:06:02 antares firewalld[8894]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/bin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP' fa>
lines 1-16/16 (END)
```

I'm using **docker-compose** for my containers.